# How do you convert a tkinter entry to an integer

Tags: python, tkinter, integer, tkinter-entry

I need to use an entry from a GUI in an equation, and I consistently get errors when attempting to convert it to an integer. The variable I'm attempting to convert is marked as "radius."

```
import math
import tkinter as tk

circ = tk.Tk()
circ.title("Circle")
circ.geometry("150x75")

radiusLabel = tk.Label(circ, text = "What is the radius?")
radiusEntry = tk.Entry(circ)

def close_window():
    circ.destroy()

radius = int(radiusEntry)

submit = tk.Button(circ, text = "Submit", command = close_window)

radiusLabel.pack()
radiusEntry.pack()
submit.pack()
circ.mainloop()

class Shape():
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.circumference = float(2) * float(radius) * float(math.pi)
        self.area = float(math.pi) * float(radius*radius)

    def getArea(self):
        return self.area

    def getPerimeter(self):
        return self.circumference

    def __str__(self):
        return "Area: %s, Circumference: %s" % (self.area, self.circumference)

circle = Shape(radius)
print(circle)
```

Comment: You could try `radius = int(radiusEntry.get())`, but it isn't going to work straight away. This is because that line is executing a millionth of a second after the window is first created, so the user probably hasn't actually entered anything into the text box yet.

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1):

U can try this function, it works for me

```
def cvtInt(value):
    fnum = []
    newnum = ''
    for i in value:
        ii = int(i)
        fnum.append(ii)
    for i in fnum:
        newnum = newnum + str(i)
    new = int(newnum)
    return new
```

Answer (score 0):

Three things that will help you with this:

1. General tip: when debugging things like this, use print statements to see if you're getting the information you're expecting. Does radiusEntry always give you a number? My guess is probably not.
2. I believe you should be using `radius = int(radiusEntry.get())` to get the input value
3. Probably your best bet is performing a check before you cast the radius to an int, and making sure that you're actually trying to convert a number. If you're trying to convert a letter or a None datatype, that could be causing your error. You can check for this using the python `isnumeric()` method for strings.

Pseudocode for you:

```
If the radius entry is a number,

   convert the radius entry to an int
```

Comment: The issue is that the code will not convert it. I've tried
    int(radiusEntry)
    int(radiusEntry.get())
and many more. I'm trying to figure out which method will actual convert the string from the entry into an integer